# How to find the amount of factors that triangle numbers have?

Tags: python

I was doing [Project Euler Problem 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12) and I ran into a problem. Here is my code:

```
def print_factors(x):
    count = 0 
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            count = count + 1
    return count
count = 0
div = 0
while True:
    if print_factors(count + count + 1) == 500:
        print(count)
        break;
    count = count + 1
```

Is there a faster way of doing this? This is taking way too long.

Comment: For one, you're not checking the triangle numbers, you're checking every odd number. `count+count+1` with `count` incrementing by one each iteration will yield the sequence 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, etc.

Comment: You don't have to check factors from 1 to x. If `n` is a factor, then `x/n` is also a factor. So you only need to check until `sqrt(x)`.

Comment: For two, yes, you need to think of a faster way to get the number of factors than brute force trial division. This is the purpose of every Project Euler problem, to make you come up with clever ways to optimize your program. The goal is not just to solve the problems but to solve them quickly. I urge you not to ask for help. Work on this some more, figure it out yourself. It'll be worth it.

Comment: Two points: (1) The problem states "What is the value of the first triangle number to have OVER five hundred divisors?" so you need to change the code to > 500, not == 500 (it may not be 500 exactly).  (2), Adding to what John Kugelman said, you need to generate triangular numbers, the formula for which is n(n + 1) / 2, so e.g. the fifth triangular number (if you count from 1, though zero is a triangular number) is 5(5 + 1) /2, which gives you (5 * 6) / 2, gives you 15.

Answer (score 0):

For every triangular number you could iterate over primes starting from 2. For every prime check how many times the number can be divided. For example 28 can be divided two times with 2 since `28 / 2 = 14` and `14 / 2 = 7`. Then multiply the amount of current divisors with times + 1. Then assign leftover to number and move to next prime. Repeat while `prime <= number`. Below is code that implements it in practice:

```
# Generate bunch of primes and cache them for efficiency
primes = [2, 3]

for i in xrange(5, 1000):
    for j in primes:
        if i % j == 0:
            break
    else:
        primes.append(i)

i = 2
while True:
    res = triangle = i * (i - 1) / 2
    divisors = 1

    for j in primes:
        if j > triangle:
            break

        cur = 1
        while triangle % j == 0:
            triangle /= j
            cur += 1

        divisors *= cur

    if divisors > 500:
        break
    i += 1

print res
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code.

```
!/usr/bin/python
primes = [2]
def fp():
    i=3
    while i<10000:
        for j in primes:
            if i%j == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(i)
        i+=1
def fac(n):
    f={}
    i = 0
    while n > 1:
        p=primes[i]
        if p*p > n :
            p=n
        while n%p==0:
            f[p]=f.get(p,0)+1
            n/=p
        i+=1
    n=1
    for i in f:
        n*=f[i]+1
    return n

from time import time
def f1():
    t=time()
    fp()
    j=0
    i=0
    max = 0
    while True:
        i+=1
        j+=i
        f=fac(j)
        if f >= 500:
            break

    print j,f
    print time()-t

f1()
```

EDITED:

primes : a list containing prime numbers from 2 to the last prime number lesser than 10000 (constructed by the fp)

fp : finds all the prime numbers lesser than 10000 and store them in "primes". We have to check prime number so many times after this so pre-finding and storing them in a list will make the whole process faster. This function is fast because 1. It goes through only prime numbers 2. It stops at the sqrt of the target number.

fac : a function to fund the number of factor of the given number. It better than brute-force because it just tries to find all the prime factors using "primes" list and again, stops at the sqrt of the target number. After it knows all the primes factor, it calculates the number of factors using some kind of combinatorial algorithm which is a multiplication of the number of each different prime factor.

Ex.: 40=(2*2*2)*(5) then 40 has (3 (+1))*(1 (+1)) = 8 factors

Explanation: You can think of it as a problem where you have 2 groups of material  ( 2 and 5 in the example ) and you want to find the number of results you can make by mixing these materials. If you focus on material '2' you could either select only one '2' to get 2 or two '2' to get 4 or three 2 to get '8' or no '2' at all to get 1 so you have 3 +1 possibilities from a prime factor that occurs 3 times. The same with '5', you have 1 +1 possibilities from selecting and unselecting it. That's how (+1) comes.

f1 : the main function. It jumps to next and next triangle number and finds the one that has more than 500 factors then stops, print the time it takes.

Comment: I quickly replaced ' ' with '\t' everywhere because the original one was very hard to read XD.

Comment: Hope that it's better now :).

Comment: Can you explain what this does and why it's better?

Answer (score 0):

This very nice solution is completely based (with a few minor corrections only) on http://www.tech-thoughts-blog.com/2012/08/1-introduction-in-this-article-i-will.html, where rahmu provides the code and excellent explanations of it, so all credit to him.  Whether it is faster than the original code or the other solutions provided, I am not sure. On my machine it produces an answer in roughly 6 seconds.

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce


def prime_factors(n):
    """
    Generates all the prime factors of a positive integer n
    :param n:
    """
    d = 2
    while n > 1:
        while n % d == 0:
            n /= d
            yield d
        d += 1


def format_prime(n):
    """
    Returns a collection.Counter() built from the prime factors decomposition of n.
    :param n:
    """
    return Counter(prime_factors(n))


def prime_count(c):
    """ c is a Counter() object holding the prime factor decomposition of an integer. It returns the total number of
    divisors by applying the following formula:
    Let N = a^x * b^y * c^z (a, b and c prime) and F(N) the total number of divisors of N.
    F(N) = (x + 1) * (y + 1) * (c + 1)
    :param c:
    """
    return reduce(mul, (c[j] + 1 for j in c))


def triangle(k):
    """
    k is an int. This function returns a collections.Counter that is the application of triangle(k) = k * (k+1) / 2.
    :param k:
    """
    a = format_prime(k)
    b = format_prime(k+1)
    c = a + b
    c[2] -= 1  # This is equivalent to a division by 2
    return c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = 2
    number_of_factors = 500
    while prime_count(triangle(i)) <= number_of_factors:
        i += 1
    print(i * (i+1) // 2)
```