# How to make my program more efficient in Python

Tags: python

*So I had to make a code which generates the first triangle number which has over 500 factors. The problem is given in detail below:*

The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:

1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...

Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:

1: 1
 3: 1,3
 6: 1,2,3,6
10: 1,2,5,10
15: 1,3,5,15
21: 1,3,7,21
28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.

What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

*I have written a block of code which generates the same however it is highly **inefficient**; kindly suggest some ways to improve it. Moreover it is so inefficient that it only works with numbers below 70*

*My code is given below, please refer:*

```
def generates_triangle_numbers_upto_n(n):
    list = [1]
    while len(list)<n:
        nth = int(len(list)+1)
        to_be_appended = nth/2 + nth**2/2
        list.append(to_be_appended)
    return list

def return_number_of_n(n):
    num = 0
    for i in range(2, int(n)):
        if n%i == 0:
            num = num+1
    return num + 2

def main(n):
    list = generates_triangle_numbers_upto_n(20000)
    for i in list:
        if return_number_of_n(i) >  int(n):
            return i

print(main(100))
```

I saw a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735028/calculating-the-first-triangle-number-to-have-over-500-divisors-in-python) question on this site but I didn't understand how it worked:

Thanks a lot!

**Edit 1:** *Thanks everyone for the wonderful suggestions, based on which I have refined my code:*

```
def main(n):
    list = [1]
    while return_number_of_n_second(list[len(list)-1]) <= n:
        nth = int(len(list)+1)
        to_be_appended = int(nth/2 + nth**2/2)
        list.append(to_be_appended)
    return list[len(list)-1]

def return_number_of_n_second(n):
    num = 0
    import math
    sqrt = math.sqrt(n) 
    for i in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))):
    if n%i == 0:
        num = num+1
    if int(sqrt) == sqrt:
        return num*2 +3
    return num*2 + 2

print(main(500))
```

*However, now too, it takes 10-15 seconds to execute. Is there a way to make it **even more efficient** since almost all of project euler's problems are to be executed in 2-3 seconds max?*

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176767/how-to-find-the-amount-of-factors-that-triangle-numbers-have

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to calculate the number of divisors of a given number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110344/algorithm-to-calculate-the-number-of-divisors-of-a-given-number)

Comment: It's not literally a dupe of course, but if you make the part of your code that counts divisors efficient, then your code should be fast enough.

Comment: Hint: `tri(n)=n(n+1)/2`, and `n` and `n+1` have no common factors, and one of them must be even. Note that Project Euler do not like it when people publish solutions to PE problems, and PE fans on SO may downvote PE questions and answers.

Comment: on a cursory glance you are constantly appending a list ,you might achieve better results using a deque .

Comment: By the way, your code has a bug -- it should test for "at least 500 factors", not "exactly 500 factors"

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176767/how-to-find-the-amount-of-factors-that-triangle-numbers-have/37177367#37177367) in the question I linked to. It runs in 0.3 sec on my machine

Comment: If your code is working, isn't [codereview.se] the better place to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Just some basic technical optimizations and it should do it:

```
import time
import math


def main(n):
    last, length = 1, 1

    while return_number_of_n_second(last) <= n:
        length += 1
        last = int(length/2 * (length+1))

    return last


def return_number_of_n_second(n):
    sqrt = math.sqrt(n)
    if int(sqrt) == sqrt:
        return 2
    return sum(1 for i in range(2, math.ceil(sqrt)) if not n % i) * 2 + 2

start_time = time.time()
print(main(500))
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

Comment: On my computer the original responds:

    76576500
    16.701260805130005

The optimized one:


    76576500
    4.333745718002319

Comment: Pardon me, but I did not understand your code below the 11the line (excluding the blank lines). Why did you write that if the object is a perfect square then return 2. By this logic, an input of 16 (which is a perfect square) would result in an output of 2 which is obviously not true since 16 has 5 factors (1 ,2 , 4, 8, 16). Kindly back up your logic with suitable explanation.